# Index out of bound when removing columns from a table (astropy)

Tags: python, astropy, fits

I have finally figured out how to edit fits table using the module "Table" from astropy.io, but I am still getting an out of bound error.
Given a table of 75.000 rows of galaxies in a fits file, I want to export into a new file all of those with ID = 13. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.table import Table
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Opening the file and printing it as a table

hdul = fits.open("data_SDSS_Info.fit")
t = Table.read(hdul)
print("Printing data_SDSS_Info in Table format...","\n")
print(t)

# Removing rows from the table and outputting the subsample into a new FITS file

for i in range(len(hdul[1].data)):
    if hdul[1].data[i][36] != 13:
        t.remove_rows(i)
        
t.write("subsample.fit",overwrite=True)
        
print("Printing subsample table...")
print(t)
```

I thought this would work fine and I can't spot any errors (though I'm sure there are more efficient ways to do this) - but still when I run this code it's **super slow**, and at the end it returns: "index 37781 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 37780"

Is there a problem in row 37781 in particular or is this caused by something weird?

If I try to extract the subsample by putting it into a normal array I don't get any error on that row...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying the table in place within the loop by removing rows but the index `i` is iterating to the length of the original table. Instead try something like:

```
remove_idxs = []
for i in range(len(hdul[1].data)):
    if hdul[1].data[i][36] != 13:
        remove_idxs.append(i)

t.remove_rows(remove_idxs)
```

This will be much faster as well because each call to `remove_rows` is relatively expensive.

Comment: Why even use remove_rows instead of indexing with a mask? I guess it might save memory...